# Problem with integers when logging to minecraft server

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a plugin for logging (authme isn't working for me), which will send you 5 messages to warn you about logging and then it will kick you. Everything works perfectly, but int i will be after this 6. I know, I can set i to 1, but what can I do, if there are logging more players?

```
int i = 1;
    
    void waitForLogin(String message, Player p) {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 60);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 120);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 180);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 240);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 300);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 360);
    }
    
    void justDoIt(String message, Player p) {
        if (may_loggin.contains(p)) {
            if (i == 6) {
                p.kickPlayer(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Cas vyprsel!");
            } else {
                p.sendMessage(message);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMAQU.png)

Comment: Please include the code as text directly in the question. A screenshot of your IDE is not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap` with the player name or ID of some sort as the key.

```
Map<String. Integer> playerCounter = new HashMap<>():
    
    void waitForLogin(String message, Player p) {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 60);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 120);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 180);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 240);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 300);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> justDoIt(message, p), 360);
    }

    void justDoIt(String message, Player p) {
        if (may_loggin.contains(p)) {
            if (i == 6) {
                p.kickPlayer(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Cas vyprsel!");
                playerCounter.remove(p.getName());
            } else {
                p.sendMessage(message);
                playerCounter.put(p.getName(), playerCounter.getOrDefault(p.getName(), 0) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Replace.`.getName()` with whatever fields player class uses to identify itself.